# iPhone images a href link not working

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, safari, href

I have a problem with links on my site not working just on the iPhone. They work everywhere else including the iPad.

I'm stuck. The page validates on W3c and it seems simple enough html. Can anybody help me. The link to the page is below.

[Site link](http://www.crosssection-online.com/2013/review.html)

Thanks

Comment: Are you running it through Safari or its your app that is running UIWebView ? If its App,
Are you using javascript ? and that is not included in the App build ? Just making sure if all things are in place.

Comment: i had used href="#" in my page and it was not working with safari. instead when i used href="javascript:void(0)" it worked fine for me.

Comment: It's running under safari. There is JQuery on the page but not on the links. This code is below

<div class ="issue"> 
 <a href ="http://www.crosssection-online.com/issue19/index.html"><img class="issueSpacing" src="reviewImages/19.png" alt ="Issue 19"></a>
<p class="strong">ISSUE 19</p>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Pratik. I've found the solution. Not really a simple one though

I was using foundation mobile framework so i changed a value from

.columns:after { clear: both; }

to

.columns:after { clear: right; }

in the foundation.css stylesheet, also I put in a smaller width for div class issue and it worked.